# What does plus operator with empty operands do in Java?

Tags: java, syntax

I am just wondering what does the compiler do when you have multiple plus operator with **empty operands**? I am aware of the pre/post increment operators. Is the compiler just adding zeroes in between?

```
        int a = 1;
        int b = + + + + + + a;
        System.out.println(b); //prints 1

        b = - - - - - - a;
        System.out.println(b); //prints 1

        b = ++a; //
        System.out.println(b); //prints 2
```

Comment: Unary positive and negative operators. It indicates that a number is positive or negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint.

As you pointed out

```
int a = 1;
int  b = - - - - - - a;
System.out.println(b); //prints 1
```

But using an odd number of - signs gives

```
b = - - - - - a;
System.out.println(b); // prints -1
```

I leave it up to you to arrive at the answer.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I accidentally used even numbers for the negative unary operators in my test, hence I thought it did not make a difference. But using an odd number of negative operators do show the difference now.

Answer (score 1):

As [Elliott Frisch has already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61856714/what-does-plus-operator-with-empty-operands-do-in-java#comment109407500_61856714), these are unary positive and negative operators. Out of `+` and `-`, the later is commonly used to change a positive number to negative and vice versa.

The following example will help you understand it more clearly:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 1;
        int b = +a;
        int c = -a;
        System.out.println("b = " + b + ", c = " + c);

        b = + +a;// + and + = +
        c = - -a;// - and - = +
        System.out.println("b = " + b + ", c = " + c);

        b = + + +a;// + (+ and +) = + and + = +
        c = - - -a;// - (- and -) = - and + = -
        System.out.println("b = " + b + ", c = " + c);

        ++b;
        ++c;
        System.out.println("b = " + b + ", c = " + c);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
b = 1, c = -1
b = 1, c = 1
b = 1, c = -1
b = 2, c = 0
```